# is possible to calculate Net Present Value with different discount rates per year?

Tags: finance

The formular for NPV is: [Net Present value formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8rAT.png)
$$\sum_{t=1}^n= \frac{Rt}{(1+i)^t}$$

where:
Rt =Net cash inflow-outflows during a single period t

i=Discount rate or return that could be earned in alternative investments

t=Number of timer periods
​

Which means taking projected cash flow for each year and dividing it by (1 + discount rate). For example this is the formula for a 5 year project and 3% discount rate:
$$\sum_{t=1}^n= \frac{Rt}{(1+0.03)^5}$$

This formula has one serious problem: considers that the discount rate does not change throughout the project. Which means for example that the risk free rate dont change in 5 years ( premise totally out of reality ). My question is very simple: is possible to consider differents rates per year for Net Present Value calculation? for example for the first year 3% for the next year 3.4% etc. If i calculate the npv for the first year with 3% of discount rate and sum by the npv for the second year with 3.4% discount rate??

To solve this doubt, I created a cashflow, separate it into two cash flows, calculated the NPV for each separately and added the same discount rate.

```
# R CODE
library(FinCal)
total_cashflow=c(10,10,10,20,60)
split1_cashflow=c(10,10)
split2_cashflow=c(10,20,60)

#Net present Value for the complete cashflow 3% discout rate
npv(0.03,total_cashflow)
> 100.7468
#Sum of Net present Value for the two split cashflows 3% discout rate
npv(0.03,split1_cashflow)+npv(0.03,split2_cashflow)
> 105.682
```

Why are the results different?

Comment: Please do not post unsearchable images of equations.  Instead, typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't know how to do this.

Comment: Here is a *MathJax* tutorial:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i edited the post.

Comment: Calculate the principal for the first $n$ years using one rate, then start at that year and calculate for the next $m$ years using the second rate.

Comment: i tried this but the results for the same cashflow at the same discount rates indicates that this approach is not right

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the first payment is made immediately then your first result is right. It starts at $t=0$ and ends at $t=4$

$$PV_1=\frac{10}{1.03^0}+\frac{10}{1.03^1}+\frac{10}{1.03^2}+\frac{20}{1.03^3}+\frac{60}{1.03^4}=100.7468 \ \ \color{\limegreen}{\checkmark}$$

The split approach begins for the first two payments at $t=0$ and ends at $t=1$. For the next three payments it begins once again at $t=0$ and ends at $t=2$.

$$PV_2=\underbrace{\frac{10}{1.03^0}+\frac{10}{1.03^1}}_{\textrm{split 1}}+\underbrace{\frac{10}{1.03^0}+\frac{20}{1.03^1}+\frac{60}{1.03^2}}_{\textrm{split 2}}=105.682 \ \ \color{red}{\times}$$

This is not the intention of the first approach.

Comment: soo if i want to calculate npv for different discount rates i have to: 10/discount_rate1^0 + 10/discount_rate1^1 + 10/discount_rate1^2 + 20/discount_rate2^3 + 60/discount_rate2^4  ?

Comment: Not really. First of all this question is different from the question in your post. Usually the discount rates are linked to the period. Let´s say you have two periods with the following discount rates and payments: $i_1=0.1,i_2=0.12,R_1=100,R_2=80$. Then the NVP is
$$\textrm{NVP}=\frac{100}{1.1}+\frac{80}{1.1\cdot 1.12}.$$
In this example the pyments are made at the end of the year. With the discount of 1.12 of the second payment you get the value of 80 at $t=1$. And then you discount again with $1.1$ and you obtain the NPV of the $80$ (t=0)

Comment: I dont understand in your first answer you say that the error is because the t= 0 occurs again but in this comment you multiply by 1.1 so the t=0 occurs again

Comment: All values of the payments have to be transformed to the present value. At split 2 we have $$\underbrace{\frac{10}{1.03^0}+\frac{20}{1.03^1}+\frac{60}{1.03^2}}_{\textrm{split 2}}$$ 

Here it is pretended that the payment 10 is made at $t=0$, the payment 20 is made at $t=1$ and the payment 60 is made at $t=2$. But this is not true. They are made at $t=2, t=3$ and $t=4$. That´s why the result is wrong at the end. To get the right result we have to discount every term twice. (continued ...)

Comment: $$\left(\frac{10}{1.03^0}+\frac{20}{1.03^1}+\frac{60}{1.03^2}\right)\cdot \frac1{1.03^2}=\frac{10}{1.03^2}+\frac{20}{1.03^3}+\frac{60}{1.03^4}$$ 

This is equal to the expression at $\textrm{PV}_1$.

Comment: yeah i understand this, my question is why is wrong to do simply:  10/discount_rate1 ^ 0 + 10/discount_rate1 ^ 1 + 10/discount_rate1 ^ 2 + 20/discount_rate2 ^ 3 + 60/discount_rate2 ^ 4 ? if my discount rate change in the 3 period for example

Comment: Because the discount rate in period 3 is only for period 3. All payments which are made at period 3 or more are affected by this discount rate at period 3-but only once. For instance the second payment $80$ at t=2 discounted only once with $1.12$.